# Combining Rintrojs with shinydashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, intro.js

I'm just getting started with the [rintrojs](https://github.com/carlganz/rintrojs) package and I would like to mix it up with the `shinydashboard` package. Especially I would like to have a step for:

- the sidebar,
- the header (which is in blue in the image)
- the button that allows to close and open the sidebar (that I surrounded in red in the image)

[image]

I tried to start from the example on their github page and to add a sixth step on the sidebar but it returns me an error

```
library(rintrojs)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- shinyUI(
  dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
    introBox(dashboardSidebar(

    ),data.step = 6,
    data.intro = 'This is the sidebar'),
    dashboardBody(
      fluidPage(
        introjsUI(),

        # Application title
        introBox(
          titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),
          data.step = 1,
          data.intro = "This is the title panel"
        ),

        # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins
        sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(
          introBox(
            introBox(
              sliderInput(
                "bins",
                "Number of bins:",
                min = 1,
                max = 50,
                value = 30
              ),
              data.step = 3,
              data.intro = "This is a slider",
              data.hint = "You can slide me"
            ),
            introBox(
              actionButton("help", "Press for instructions"),
              data.step = 4,
              data.intro = "This is a button",
              data.hint = "You can press me"
            ),
            data.step = 2,
            data.intro = "This is the sidebar. Look how intro elements can nest"
          )
        ),

        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
          introBox(
            plotOutput("distPlot"),
            data.step = 5,
            data.intro = "This is the main plot"
          )
        ))
      )
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  # initiate hints on startup with custom button and event
  hintjs(session, options = list("hintButtonLabel"="Hope this hint was helpful"),
         events = list("onhintclose"=I('alert("Wasn\'t that hint helpful")')))

  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
    x    <- faithful[, 2]
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

    # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
    hist(x,
         breaks = bins,
         col = 'darkgray',
         border = 'white')
  })

  # start introjs when button is pressed with custom options and events
  observeEvent(input$help,
               introjs(session, options = list("nextLabel"="Onwards and Upwards",
                                               "prevLabel"="Did you forget something?",
                                               "skipLabel"="Don't be a quitter"),
                       events = list("oncomplete"=I('alert("Glad that is over")')))
  )
})

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

> Error in tagAssert(sidebar, type = "aside", class = "main-sidebar") : 
>     Expected tag to be of type aside

Second question : Is it possible to navigate between the different menu items of the sidebar within one unique rintrojs presentation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's probably too late for you, but maybe not for others who'd walk around this question like I just did.

The first trick is to implement the intro logic on the **server** side.
The second trick is to point to elements with their *class*, instead of their *id*. It can have side effects, but in your simple case, works like a charm.

```
library(rintrojs)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- shinyUI(
    dashboardPage(
        dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
        dashboardSidebar(
            introjsUI(),
            sidebarMenu(
                menuItem("Item1", tabName="item1", icon=icon("dashboard")),
                menuItem("Item2", tabName="item2", icon=icon("thumbs-up"))
            )
        ),
        dashboardBody(
            fluidPage(
                titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),
                sidebarLayout(
                    sidebarPanel(
                        sliderInput("bins", "Number of bins:", min = 1, max = 50, value = 30),
                        actionButton("help", "Press for instructions"),
                    ),
                    mainPanel(
                        plotOutput("distPlot"),
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
    steps <- reactive(
        data.frame(
            element=c(".sidebar-menu", ".main-header", ".sidebar-toggle", ".active", "#help"),
            intro=c(
                "This is a sidebar. Note that we access it with '.' instead of '#', because we track its class and not its id.",
                "This is a header.",
                "This is a button that allows to close and open the sidebar.",
                "This is the active element of the sidebar.",
                "This is a button that I added just to show the normal way to point to elements: with their id."
            ),
            position=c("right", "bottom", "bottom", "right", "top")
        )
    )
    observeEvent(input$help,
        introjs(session,
            options = list(steps=steps(),
                "nextLabel"="Next",
                "prevLabel"="Previous",
                "skipLabel"="Skip"
            ),
            events = list("oncomplete"=I('alert("Done")'))
        )
    )

    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
        x <- faithful[, 2]
        bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)
        hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
    })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

As for your second question, to the best of my knowledge, you can't.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your second question:

As @Vongo (I think rightly) pointed out, this is not directly possible.

Having said that, I found a hacky way that allows you to address different parts.
As mentioned before, the trick is to address the elements by **class** not **id**, looking at the output of `menuItem()`, we see that the highest element (`li`) does not get a class...

```
shinydashboard::menuItem("Menu 1", tabName = "menu_1")
#> <li>
#>   <a href="#shiny-tab-menu_1" data-toggle="tab" data-value="menu_1">
#>     <span>Menu 1</span>
#>  </a>
#> </li>
```

What we can do is to overload the `menuItem` function to assign a class.

WARNING, this is only slightly tested and might break some parts of your app, especially, if you pass options by position and not by name (i.e., `menuItem("Menu 1", "menu_1")` is a lot more dangerous than `menuItem(text = "Menu 1", tabName = "menu1")`).

```
menuItem <- function(text, tabName, ...) {
  r <- shinydashboard::menuItem(text, ...)
  r$attribs <- append(r$attribs, list(class = tabName))
  r
}

menuItem("Menu 1", tabName = "menu_1")
#> <li class="menu_1">
#>   <a href="#">
#>     <span>Menu 1</span>
#>   </a>
#> </li>
```

With this override, we are able to address the first menu as `.menu_1`.

See the following example for a more thorough example:

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(rintrojs)

menuItem <- function(text, tabName, ...) {
  r <- shinydashboard::menuItem(text, ...)
  r$attribs <- append(r$attribs, list(class = tabName))
  r
}

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Menu 1", tabName = "menu_1"),
      menuItem("Menu 2", tabName = "menu_2"),
      actionButton("btn_info", "Help")
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    introjsUI()
  )
)

steps_general <- tibble::tribble(
  ~element, ~intro,
  NA, "First Empty State",
  ".menu_1", "First Item",
  ".menu_2", "Second Item"
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$btn_info, introjs(session, options = list(steps = steps_general)))
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

## Edit

A less intrusive but more labor-intensive workaround is this:

```r
# adds a class to a shiny element
add_class <- function(x, class) {
  x$attribs <- append(x$attribs, list(class = class))
  x
}
```

which can then be used in the UI code

```r
#...
sidebarMenu(
  menuItem("Menu 1", tabName = "view_1") %>% add_class("view_1")
)

# alternatively without the pipe:
sidebarMenu(
  add_class(menuItem("Menu 1", tabName = "view_1"), "view_1")
)


# ...
actionButton("btn_info", "Help") %>% add_class("btn_info")

# ...
plotOutput("plot1") %>% add_class("plot1")

# etc
```

A complete example can be found [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/DavZim/56c64345c59f893a0503e5a424ba3f21).